# Windows 8.1 with CIFS Share Freezes File Explorer

Tags: cifs, windows-8.1, emc-vnxe

We have recently migrated all of our network files over to a CIFS share. We have remapped the drives on our computers, but are encountering a very specific problem with several users who have Surface Pro 3 tablets running Windows 8.1. The problem is basically as follows: If the user boots the surface while connected to the network, then disconnects it from the network, the computer is then unable to access the file explorer. Whenever the computer is connected back to the network everything is fine. If the user starts the computer and isn't connected to the network everything is fine also. The problem only seems to occur when using a CIFS Share, connecting to the network, then disconnecting from the network. Has anyone reported this problem before and is there any known work around?